# Bring a row that is not in one of the 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query in sql

```
SELECT 
    SI_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo),
    SI_Ubicacion = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion),
    SI_OV = COALESCE(c.SI_OV,''),
    SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = COALESCE(c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,''),
    SI_Existencia = COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0),
    SI_Cantidad = COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0), 
    SI_Cantidad2 = (SELECT COALESCE(c2.SI_Cantidad,0) 
        FROM SI_Conteo c2 
        WHERE  c2.SI_Num_Conteo = 2 /*AND c2.SI_Num_Articulo = 200002*/
            AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c2.SI_Ubicacion),
    SI_Dif =  COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0),
    SI_Dif_Dinero = (COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad,0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia,0)) * COALESCE(m.SI_Costo_Promedio,0)  
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t 
LEFT JOIN SI_Conteo c
    ON (t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo 
        AND c.SI_Num_Conteo = 1
        AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion)
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m 
    ON (t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
        OR c.SI_Num_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo) 
WHERE c.SI_Num_Articulo = 200002 
    OR t.SI_Articulo = 200002
```

Which brings me the next result

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mpsb.png)

My problem is that in the SI_Conteo table I have the same reference added, but it does not exist in the SI_SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD table so it does not show it to me.

This is the one that does not bring me

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0buQa.png)

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: You might need to switch to a `FULL JOIN` instead of `LEFT`.

Comment: The problem of putting `FULL OUTER JOIN` is that it brings me the ones that are in `c.SI_Num_Conteo = 2` and I only need to show the ones that are in `c.SI_Num_Conteo = 1`

Comment: Of course it isn't returned. You said it isn't in SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD which is the base table of your query. Maybe you need to move some tables around in your query and pull from the SI_Conteo or perhaps a right join??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your problem that the reference in the table "SI_Conteo" and not in the table "SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD", 
you may need to use right join like:

```
 SI_Conteo right join SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD
```

or use left like:

```
SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD left join SI_Conteo
```